# How to not obfuscate class names but get the right simplename anyway?

Tags: obfuscation, android-proguard, matomo, piwiktracker, adjust-android

I have over 20 Fragments which extends from MyFragment e.g.:

- `LoginFragment extends MyFragment`
- `UploadFragment extends MyFragment`
- `CameraFragment extends MyFragment`
- etc..

and `MyFragment` in turn extends from `Fragment` . So in my Android app, and whenever I inflate one of them, I call in my abstrac t class a `showFragment(MyFragment f)` where I fire the Adjust event,

```
AdjustEvent event = new AdjustEvent(EVENT_LOAD_FRAGMENT);
// Add callback parameters to this parameter.
event.addCallbackParameter("LoadFragment", 
f.getClass().getSimpleName());
Adjust.trackEvent(event);
```

so that I can measure what fragment is how often used as kay value pair. So far so good, and during debug phase it works nice.

As you can imagine now, the `getClass().getSimpleName()` is being obfuscated in the produtction environment. I do not want to touch all the 20 Fragments and would be totally fine if the classes get obfuscated. But I still would like to get the class' valid `getSimpleName()` String..

**How can I get a classes valid `getSimpleName()` after it was obfuscated?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used

```
-keepnames class  * extends com.you.package.name.MyFragment
```

unpacked the aar and classes.jar, and checked the build forlder for seeds.txt and mapping.txt to see the obfuscation

Answer (score 0):

add below to your proguard configuration file.

```
-keep,allowobfuscation class  * extends com.you.package.name.MyFragment
```

Comment: Can you explain, what this is doing? Isn't `keep` and `allowobfuscation` not contradictory?

Comment: How can I test it?

Comment: @shizen keep and allowobfuscation did not work. I sed `keepnames` only

Comment: `keep,allowobfuscation`  is to try the **best effort** for keeping names but also allow any possible obfuscation, if this is not what you want, yes, you need to use a weaker format, e.g. `keepnames`.